# Can I combine INSERT, JOIN and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, join, on-duplicate-key

Here's my database structure as it stands today...

`inventory_transactions` store movements of inventory with `quantity_offset` value that is either negative or positivie. They also have an `inventory_transaction_id`

`shipments` store shipments, which are groups of `inventory_transactions` with a `shipment_id`

The relationship between `inventory_transactions` and `shipments` is in a table called `shipment_inventory_transactions`

What I would like to be able to do is increment the `quantity_offset` of an `inventory_transaction` that is associated with a given `shipment` (increase the quantity of a given inventory item within the shipment) if that item already exists in the shipment.

If the item doesn't exist, create the required rows in `inventory_transactions` and `shipment_inventory_transactions`

I think some combination of `JOIN` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` can do this, but I can't wrap my head around it.

To simplify the situation, I'm considering removing the `shipment_inventory_transactions` table because the relationship between shipments and inventory_transactions is now going to be 1-to-1. The only gotcha here is that each inventory_transaction can either be associated with a shipment or a receipt, but not both. Storing them both in the same column sounds skanky. But I don't love having an extra column in every row as only one or the other will be used.

Wooh... Brain dump complete. If this made sense and you can provide a sensible answer that has eluded me, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I found simplifying the database to eliminate the many-to-many relationship let me accomplish what I wanted with a simple Insert. Better to simplify at this point than add great complexity that'll become problematic as the application grows.